# IBM Rhapsody cannot see license server

Tags: installation, license-key, rhapsody, ibm-rational

We have multiple academic licenses for Rational Rhapsody but it seems we can still not get the application working. We have the license file on one of our machines but the other machines cannot see the one machine which serves as license server.

The error message is

> The Networking Software (WINSOCK) could not obtain the IP address of the computer "SPL-X60S".

Any help?

Comment: https://www.fsf.org/bulletin/2007/fall/antifeatures/

Comment: This looks a like a questio for serverfault.

Comment: @PreetSangha how can I move my question to there?

Comment: @awoodland wholeheartedly agree with you! This licensing stuff is a corporate nightmare. But alas that does not help my students to get their copies working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found on a academic network, depending on the network you are in, sometimes its as simple `27000@<hostname>` for a server if all your keys are on one computer. However at the university I work at the computer science department and the CS network doesn't allow it. So we haven't found any other way than correct security settings, and NOT being on the CS server exclusively.

Try `27000@<hostname>`

Comment: Sorry thats 27000@"<hostname>"

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me if the sever computer and myself were off the VPN and the server's firewall was turned off. However, this only works for an hour after the firewall is turned back on.